# Words to mean ‘form a family’

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the appropriate word to use in this context:

> in 1996, Dad met my mom, and they fell in love, decided to get married, have children and.....a family.

Should I say ‘form a family’? I think it is not idiomatic. Is there another word, or words, to give the same meaning?

Comment: _start_ a family _(form_ a company, maybe!) Questions like this are probably better off on https://ell.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definition of **start a family**  [merriam-webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/start%20a%20family)

:

> to begin having children

As in:

> They want to start a family soon.